# What is the communication port between Namenode and Datanode in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, port, ubuntu-16.04, namenode, datanode

I want to know the communication protocol specifically `port number` used by Namenode and Datanode in hadoop.

Say, if I write the following command in Namenode,

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

it will show the details of live nodes (namenode & datanode), how many datanodes are there etc. My question is how namenode and datanode communicates ? via `which port`? I am actually getting only 1 datanode with the above command whereas in my cluster, there are 8 datanodes. So, I am not sure whether any `port blocking of networking` is caused this!! My firewall is disabled in the namenode and all the datanodes. I have checked this via `sudo ufw status` command which returned `inactive`.

From hadoop official pages ([link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html)), I have found this:

> The Communication Protocols
>
> All HDFS communication protocols are layered on top of the TCP/IP
>   protocol. A client establishes a connection to a configurable TCP port
>   on the NameNode machine. It talks the ClientProtocol with the
>   NameNode. The DataNodes talk to the NameNode using the DataNode
>   Protocol. A Remote Procedure Call (RPC) abstraction wraps both the
>   Client Protocol and the DataNode Protocol. By design, the NameNode
>   never initiates any RPCs. Instead, it only responds to RPC requests
>   issued by DataNodes or clients.

I am using `hadoop 3.1.1` in `Ubuntu 16.04`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all configured in `hdfs-site.xml`.

For example, by default, `dfs.datanode.address=0.0.0.0:9866`

If you search for `port` or `address`, then you can generally find what you are looking for https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

If that command or the NameNode UI don't show datanodes, then SSH to the individual nodes, check `jps` to see if process is running, and log files to find if the process is not running.